# Using CollectionAssert

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio-2010, unit-testing

If I had a custom class that inherits from Collection called `LookUpValueCollection` that handle only types of the class `LookUpValueCollection`, to use the method `CollectionAssert` with Visual Studio test Do I need to implement the method IEqual to handle the comparison? Because I used and despite of two collection are similar still says that the objets inside are different.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, the elements of the collection need to override `Equals` (and `GetHashCode`). Otherwise, the elements will be compared by reference, so they won't be considered equal if they're not the same instance.